# Counting and Combining Instances in an ArrayList

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have the following class that consists of an ArrayList constructor and a method that is intended to count and combine the instances of objects based on their assigned name. The methods `getName()` and `getCost` are supplied in an additional class. The objects are described by a String (name) and a double (cost).

```
import java.util.*;
public class InventoryDemo
{
    public static void takeInventory(List<Product> products)
    {
        String[] names = new String[products.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i ++)
        {
            String currentName = products.get(i).getName();
            names[i] = currentName;
            double totalCost = products.get(i).getCost();
            int quantity = 0;
            for (int i2 = 1; i2 < products.size() - 1; i2 ++)
            {
                if (products.get(i).getName() == products.get(i2).getName())
                {
                   quantity ++;
                   totalCost = totalCost + products.get(i2).getCost();
                }
            }
            System.out.print(currentName + ": Quantity = " + quantity);
            System.out.println(", Total Cost = " + totalCost);   
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {       
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();        
            Car car1 = new Car("Jaguar", 1000000.00);
            products.add(car1);
            Car car2 = new Car("Neon", 17000.00);
            products.add(car2);
            Tool saw1 = new Tool("JigSaw", 149.18);
            products.add(saw1);
            Car car3 = new Car("Jaguar", 110000.00);
            products.add(car3);
            Car car4 = new Car("Neon", 17500.00);
            products.add(car4);
            Car car5 = new Car("Neon", 17875.32);
            products.add(car5);
            Truck truck1 = new Truck("RAM", 35700.00);
            products.add(truck1);
            Tool saw2 = new Tool("CircularSaw", 200.00);
            products.add(saw2);
            Tool saw3 = new Tool("CircularSaw", 150.00);
            products.add(saw3);
        takeInventory(products);
    }
}
```

The output is supposed to show each specific object (based on name) along with the number they appear and their combined cost. However, its output is greatly incorrect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your inner loop control variable is incorrect because it's always starting at index `1` whereas it should start at `i + 1` in proportion to the outer loop, therefore your inner loop should be:

```
for (int i2 = i + 1; i2 < products.size() - 1; i2++)
```

Another thing is you're supposed to compare strings with [`.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

```
if (products.get(i).getName().equals(products.get(i2).getName()))
```

Comment: I see, I was using a conditional operator as opposed to the String operator. Thank you very much.